# .bash: command still not found after adding path in M1 terminal (stacked_cli)

Tags: flutter, bash, dart, terminal

I have installed this CLI - https://stacked.filledstacks.com/docs/getting-started/overview

The downloaded file is saved in this folder user/.pub-cache/global_packages

When I typed stacked create app my_first_app

I got this error -bash: stacked: command not found

I can see that I added the path when I typed echo $PATH

From my terminal:

```
echo $PATH

/opt/homebrew/opt/dart@2.16/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Users/alexa/opt/anaconda3/bin:/Users/alexa/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.1/bin:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:/Users/alexa/.pub-cache/bin:/Users/alexa/Developer/flutter/bin
```

this is the path I added :/Users/alexa/.pub-cache/bin:

My login shell is /bin/bash and I saved the path to nano ~/.bash_profile

Comment: so is the file in ```/Users/alexa/.pub-cache/bin``` or ```/Users/alexa/.pub-cache/global_packages``` ?

Comment: @flappix it is saved to /Users/alexa/.pub-cache/global_packages.  I just changed the path to export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/global_packages" ...still got the same error

Comment: And in the directory you add to the path, you can see a file `stacked` with executable permissions?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I don't have a file named stacked in the path Users/alexa/.pub-cache/global_packages ...I do have a Unix Executable File named st_cli in the bin folder (/Users/alexa/.pub-cache/bin)

Comment: I don't know anything about stacked and how it's installed, but for any command (that isn't a built-in, an alias, or a function), there has to exist a file with the name you're using, with executable permissions, in your `PATH`.

Comment: I think i found the problem....

the latest version of the library is 1.1.0 but I don't why it has activated version 1.0.16...I am not sure why it is not downloading the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it...looks like the problem was I didn't install the latest version of the CLI because I was using an older version of the Dart SDK. My Dart SDK was updated but I had to remove the path referencing the older version of the Dart SDK.